# Calculating conditional probability from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, probability

Trying to calculate the conditional probability from a given list. Say I have the following list:

```
[[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5],
 [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3],
 [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Each 'column' represents a binary attribute, the last 'column' is the class attribute. To find conditional probability of an attribute, I need to calculate `P(X|Y)`.

In Python list, how can I

1. count the number of frequency of the attribute given it is a Y class?
2. count the total frequency for the class?

The above is easily doable in pandas, but I am actually clueless on how to tackle it with a Python list.

Comment: Naive way, use loops. If you list of lists is called `P`:
1) `P[i][j]` where `i` runs on row indices, `j` on column indices, gets you each element and you can count if they are 1 or 0.
2) `P[i][-1]` gets you the last element of each row `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> frequency of the attribute given it is a Y class?

```py
class_ = 3
attr_index = 1
attr_freq_given_cls = sum(a_list[attr_index]
                          for a_list in list_of_lists
                          if a_list[-1] == class_)
```

Since attributes are from `{0, 1}`, `sum`ming yields the number of occurences; and indexing with `-1` gives the label.

> count the total frequency for the class?

```py
from collections import Counter
class_freqs = Counter(a_list[-1] for a_list in list_of_lists)
```

good luck with that naive Bayes :)

Comment: Thanks! May I check for `attr_index = 1`, is 1 the first column or the first column should start with 0 like in pandas dataframe?

Comment: @datanewbie96 First column is indexed by 0 yes.

Comment: Ic! What will be a good approach to getting the attribute frequency divided by the class frequency? I will need to extract the class frequency from the counter list and do some IF conditions?

Comment: @datanewbie96 yes

Answer (score 2):

You could build a data structure along these lines:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0]))

for *values, key in matrix:
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        d[key][i][v] += 1
```

And calculate the conditional probability like so:

```
def prob(k, i):
    false, true = d[k][i]  # counts of vals 0/1 in col i for class k
    return true / (true + false)

>>> prob(5, 3)  # for class 5, column 3 is this likely to be 1
0.0
>>> prob(5, 4)
1.0
```